# 'new-line character seen in unquoted field'-error when trying to write to a csv-file in Python

Tags: python, file, csv, newline, read-write

I created a Python script where I want to read a file, preprocess it and write it as a CSV file.

However, when I try to create a new line on every ")"-character I get a problem that says: "new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?" I've seen some suggesting trying to use both 'rU' and 'rb' as mode parameters, and I tried this without luck. Any other suggestions?

This is what my script looks like:

```
with open('testlogs', 'r', newline='') as log_file, open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
contents = log_file.read()  
dataPoints = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', contents)
parsedLog = [item.replace(' ', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '\n') for item in dataPoints]

reader = csv.reader(parsedLog)
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: The error message means your regex matched across a line boundary.

Comment: tried you code but I didn't get this problem - can you provide the input file ? also, what was the source, was the CSV written by Excel? on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest using re.sub (python) to manipulating regex

```
import fileinput
import re

logfile="error.log"
outfile="clean.csv"

with open("error.log") as f:
   newText = f.read()
   newText = re.sub(r" ", "", newText)
   newText = re.sub(r"(", "", newText)
   newText = re.sub(r")", "\n", newText)    

   with open("clean.csv", "w") as f:
      f.write(newText)
```

if you want to add some parameter in first line .csv file, just add it at the end of source code above:

```
for line in fileinput.input(files=['clean.csv'], inplace=True):
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
        print 'parameter1,parameter2,parameter3, .... '
    print line,
```

hope this answer help you ^_^ cheers

Comment: I tried this but it gives me another error: "re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0" on the line with "newText = re.sub(r"(", "", newText)".

Comment: try this `newText = re.sub(r"\(", "", newText)` and `newText = re.sub(r"\)", "\n", newText)`

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Is it possible to use findall aswell to keep all the data that matches a regex like I did before with this line: dataPoints = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', contents) ?